# How to find the polarization (phase) of the virtual source if image theory is used

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, microwave, pcb-antenna, propagation

Consider a radiating element (actual source) is placed above a ground plane, and if we apply image theory to determine the E-filed, the virtual source will be placed below the ground plane and ground plane is removed.

I understand how and why image theory is applied, but what I don't understand is that, how to choose the polarization (phase) of the virtual source. I would be grateful if someone can help me with this problem.

I studied this part in an antenna book but i don't understand the explanation, which is as follow:
[image]

and the figure is: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Polarization and phase are not the same thing.

[Polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_%28waves%29) is the plane that the electric field oscillates in (the magnetic field is at right angles to it). In a vertical antenna the electric field is vertically oriented, so the EM wave will also have vertical polarization. Polarization angle is not changed by reflection, so a vertically polarized wave will still be vertically polarized when reflected (thus "the polarization of the reflected waves must be as indicated").

[image]

[Phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_%28waves%29) is the relative angle *in time* between waves. If two waves are going up and down at exactly the same time then they are 'in phase', and when combined their amplitudes will add ('constructive' interference). If they are 'out of phase' then the combined signal will not be as strong ('destructive' interference), the weakest point being when the phase difference is 180°.

[image]

Reflection may cause a phase change depending on the angle of reflection, polarization of the incident wave (vertical E field is close to in phase at angles over about 30°, horizontal E field is always 180° out of phase) reflecting material and frequency. But phase also changes with distance, so two waves that start out in (or out) of phase may not be so after traveling over paths with different lengths. As the reception point is moved the the phase difference will continually change from constructive to destructive and back, so the signal will fade in and out.

Comment: I would like to thank you dear Bruce Abbott. It's more clear to me, because I used to think polarization and phase are almost the same thing when it comes to antenna. But the part that I still haven't understood is that, if I am to derive array factor, actual source and image source will have different phase of 180 degree. Why is it so? For example, if actual source is placed above and it has phase of 0, after removing the ground plane and placing the image source, it should have phase of 180 degree. @BurceAbbott

Comment: And I wonder if you can explain the part that I did quote from the book, "According to the boundary conditions, the tangential components of the electric field must vanish at all points along the interface. Thus for an incident electric field with vertical polarization shown by the arrows, the polarization of the reflected waves must be as indicated in the figure to satisfy the boundary conditions." @BurceAbbott